# Add to the beginning of the pdf page depending on the number of pages

Tags: php, tcpdf

I need to add pages to the beginning of the pdf if the number of all pages is not a multiple of 4.

At the end of the document, I can do it like this:

```
$total = $pdf->getNumPages();
if ($total % 4 != 0) {
  $left_pages =  $total % 4;
  for($i=1; $i<=$left_pages; $i++) {
        $pdf->AddPage('P', 'A5');
  }
}
```

But at the beginning of the code $pdf->getNumPages() is 0 and this code doesn't work. How to get the number of all pages at the beginning or do it in another way?

Comment: Well, I think you need to create the page, get its position and move it to the first position.

Answer (score 0):

Thx @esQmo_ for the idea. When creating page, use the movePage() method.

> Well, I think you need to create the page, get its position and move
> it to the first position. –  esQmo_

```
$total = $pdf->getNumPages();
if ($total % 4 != 0) {
  $left_pages =  $total % 4;
  for($i=1; $i<=$left_pages; $i++) {
        $pdf->AddPage('P', 'A5');
        $nump = $pdf->getPage();
        $pdf->movePage($nump,1);
  }
}
```